# String concatenate in perl?

Tags: perl

I apologize if this question is too basic, but I'm really very very new to perl. Now I want to write the following two lines of code in one line:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("my_password","\$6\$my_salt\$")'

perl -pe 's|(root):(\$.*?:)|\1:my_encrypted_password:|' /etc/shadow
```

Basically I want to replace the `my_encrypted_password` with what's being printed from the first line. But I have no idea how to write it correctly? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if modifying `/etc/shadows` with perl is really a good idea...

Comment: I'm trying to mount the virtual machine's disk to the host and reset the virtual machine's root password.

Comment: Maybe `passwd -R` might be a better solution.

Comment: @michas can you make it a bit more clear how to use `passwd -R`? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `man passwd`. Just add the mount point of your VM disk and `passwd` should use the shadow file there.

Comment: `passwd -R /path/to/vm/root/on/host root` doesn't work, the error message is: `passwd: Cannot determine your user name`. I checked both `/etc/password` and `/etc/shadow`, the entries for root both exist. I tried `passwd -R / root` to change the host root password, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean something like this:

```
perl -pe 's|(?<=root:)[^:]*|crypt("my_password","\$6\$my_salt\$")|e' /etc/shadow
```

From `perldoc perlre`:

```
    Substitution-specific modifiers described in

    "s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer" in perlop are:

      e  - evaluate the right-hand side as an expression
```

On the right side you can use `$&` to refer to the matching part and `$1` for the first captured part and so on.